# RTS522A SD card reader on Lenovo P14s not working in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: drivers, lenovo, sd-card

I have installed Ubuntu 22.10 (`uname -a` says `5.19.0-23-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct 14 15:39:57 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`) on Lenovo P14s laptop.

There is built-in SD card reader, which does not work. I. e., when I insert SD card, it is not mounted. The same SD card works on some older Lenovo laptop with some older version of Ubuntu (so it is not some "special" SD card).

`lspci` says:

```
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [17aa:5094]
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue with a P14s Laptop. Plugging In/Out an sd card has no effect in the output of dmesg. However, when I run:

```
lspci -knn | grep -iA2 card
```

which produces the ouptut

```
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [17aa:5082]
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

fixes it for me and I immediately see in the dmesg output the card:

```
[117660.732463] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
[117660.791986] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, quota, no debug enabled
[117733.612184] mmc0: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[117733.737760] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address aaaa
[117733.745451] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa WD32G 29.7 GiB 
[117733.747763]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
```

To the best of my knowledge, the lspci should only list the devices, but apparently, in my setup it triggers something so that the card is recognized.

Maybe this works for you too and helps you at least as a temporary workaround/solution.

Comment: It may be related to some power saving software like TLP, etc.

Comment: How weird. Was just having the same issue, and tried your solution, and same thing happened - immediately detected. I'm using Artix Linux kernel 6.2.13. At other times, it has appeared as if waiting some minutes resulted in detection, but this time nothing after ~10m and several re-insertions, so I went googling.

Answer (score 0):

`modprobe rtsx_pci`

fixed it to me.

Comment: Details please.

Comment: I don't see anything to detail. As others already pointed out, it uses the `rtsx_pci` module, so I ran `modprobe rtsx_pci`, then it worked after that. Just like reported in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

this fixed for me on a thinkpad l14:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtsx_pci_sdmmc
sudo modprobe rtsx_pci_sdmmc
```

it's widely know in the community that some modules for Sd card readers do not work properly on boot, so you have to restart then yourself